# Azure Start/Stop VMs during off-hours Solution - Selecting VMs by Tags

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-automation

I've been using the Start/Stop VMs during off-hours Solution for a while now and I wanted to know if there's a way to re-select affected VMs by a tag and not by Resource Group, maybe throughout recreation of the Solution even.
I tried looking that up and I've only seen usage of this Solution with a selection of affected VMs by Resource Groups and excluding VMs using the External_ExcludeVMNames Variable.
Anyone knows a way to select affected VMs by a tag?

Comment: Have you tried writing your own script?  If so, what challenges are you having?  The pre-built solution simply queries by the resource group name so its not a difficult move to change it to query for resources by tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the powershell in this script:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Stop-Start-AzureVM-535c2414

Instead of just checking that the VM exists, check the Tag of the VM

Comment: Am I supposed to add this Powershell script as a new Runbook in the solution's automation account?